# Creating a PDF 1.3 File with Unicode text strings - I think I have a Font/Encoding problem?

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to modify an existing PDF 1.3 report creating program (with its own routines for creating the PDF) so that it can handle unicode text (in addition to the existing normal text). However, it looks as though I'm not managing to select the font/encoding up correctly as displaying the created PDF isn't showing the correct glyphs for unicode values beyond the normal 256 char encoding range.

For unicode strings, I can create hex encoded UTF16BE strings for the content stream, as follows:

```
q
0 0 0 1 K 1 w 0 0 0 1 k
BT /F1 20 Tf 10 811.889764 Td     <feff00540065007300740069006e006700200075006e00690063006f0064006500200074006500780074003a0020002703a8063c017d0027> Tj ET

Q
```

in the page's Resources/Fonts dictionary I have an entry for /F1 as follows

```
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /TrueType 
/BaseFont /LucidaSansUnicodeRegular >>
```

I've tried changing the BaseFont to /LucidaSansUnicode (and others like /Arial or /Helvetica)
but this doesn't change the appearance of the created PDF.

The file is marked as PDF1.3

while normal (ASCII range) characters are displaying OK, the Byte order mark is displaying as what looks like one or two overprinted characters, and the non-ASCII range characters aren't showing the
correct glyphs.

It looks as though I'm having problems selecting the font and/or handling unicode values - I suspect the PDF may be falling back to a default font and encoding.

Does anyone have a sample PDF1.3 file that uses UTF16BE unicode that I can have a look at, or know what I need to do for the Font dictionary? I'm assuming that I may need to use a TrueType font, since that may have internal CMAP data for mapping unicode chars - but I suspect that I may need to add extra stuff in the Font dictionary as well.

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to find anything obvious in the PDF1.7 PDF spec - in some places it appears to imply that omitting the /Encoding entry may be the thing to do if you want to handle more than 256 chars, but I haven't managed to find a unicode example of how to set the Font up.

Comment: Text strings in page content aren't UTF16BE. They consist of a sequence of single-byte or multi-byte codepoints, whose interpretation depends upon the font in use. In addition, you have not provided a font. Fonts are typically embedded in PDF files. Just naming the font won't do anything, unless it's one of the Standard 14 PDF fonts. I'm afraid to say that this task is a lot harder than you are supposing.